# How to use automatic renewal of access tokens in a clustered environment?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I have successfully run a single instance of Spring Authorization Server alongside individual instances of the client and resource servers. The automatic renewal of access tokens functions properly in this setup.

However, when attempting to deploy the authorization server in a clustered environment, the access token renewal feature no longer works as expected.

I actually simulated a clustered environment using docker compose with Nginx as proxy and two instances of Spring Authorization Server.

Upon debugging the client application, I observed that the `getResponse` method of `DefaultRefreshTokenTokenResponseClient` is making a call to `http://localhost:9000/oauth2/token`. However, the authorization server responds with a redirect to `http://localhost:9000/login`, causing the `getTokenResponse` method to throw a `NullPointerException`.

The specific error message is as follows:

> Cannot invoke "org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse.getAccessToken()" because "tokenResponse" is null.

In the authorization server configuration, I've incorporated Spring Session to manage sessions and implemented a key rotation strategy inspired by [Rob Winch's implementation](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-enterprise-authorization-server). Both these components store data in a database.

Even if I configure the client to use `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`, it seems that Spring Session is unable to act as a proxy in front of it. I can see the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.AUTHORIZED_CLIENTS` in `SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES`, but the client application fails.

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
    return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
}
```

I was able to resolve this issue by configuring stick sessions in the proxy.

```
http {
  upstream loadbalancer {
    ip_hash;  ## Sticky session
    server authz1:9000;
    server authz2:9000;
  }
```

However, I initially anticipated that Spring Session could address this concern as well. Now, I'm uncertain whether I've made a mistake in my setup, or if Spring Authorization Server and Spring Session are simply not suited to handle this particular configuration. Should I consider abandoning Spring Session in favor of a stick session configuration, or is there a solution that I might be overlooking?

Comment: Did you happen to implement a custom `OAuth2AuthorizationService`? According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/core-model-components.html#oauth2-authorization-service), this is the central authorization component, and defaults to an in-memory implementation which would not work in a clustered environment. I'd make sure that you have an implementation of this component tailored for your data store.

Comment: Note that there is a `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService` provided in the framework that may work for you, or you can use it as a reference and build your own. There's also the [how-to guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/guides/how-to-jpa.html#authorization-service) for doing this with JPA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [configure `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/e5fcbe422be1a73240ac7d8b40f165651fb01ab8/samples/demo-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/config/AuthorizationServerConfig.java#L171-L175) as in the official sample to persist authorizations to a database. If a relational database does not work for you, you can build your own `OAuth2AuthorizationService` for your chosen data store.

By persisting authorizations in a database, the `refresh_token` can be used to refresh the `access_token` no matter which instance in the cluster is chosen to service the request.

Comment: I configured `JdbcOAuth2AuthorizedClientService` in the client application. The `OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter`'s `attemptAuthentication` throws **authorization_request_not_found**. This might be due to the `HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository` use which is the default implementation of `AuthorizationRequestRepository`. A solution for a clustered environment could be to provide an `AuthorizationRequestRepository` implementation to store in cookie instead of session?

Comment: I'd recommend you use Spring Session to back `HttpSession` with persistence and make it accessible across the cluster.

Comment: A NullPointerException occurred in the `JwtGenerator` because it couldn't find the "sid" claim (Session Id from `SessionInformation`) in the Id Token. The `SessionRegistryImpl` also stores sessions in memory. I could find in the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/spring-security.html#spring-security-concurrent-sessions) instructions on how to replace the default implementation. Our application is currently running in a clustered environment, with all data stored in the database.